# Why my Solidity Ethereum Contract ran out of gas?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

truffle migrate --reset

## Compiling your contracts...

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 672197500 (0x2810eb7c)

## 1_initial_migration.js

### Replacing 'Migrations'

> transaction hash:    0xf41feee2b768ba375d95ded5c40a48e7af3d59554f616738102a2a9805824d77
> Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
> contract address:    0xe75Ea4aDD9728c9846778a695cE0CF32b66C1c52
> block number:        1
> block timestamp:     1621246185
> account:             0x33b005e2f8d83120b4ab4bDde1bD7Ad704077801
> balance:             99.99626098
> gas used:            186951 (0x2da47)
> gas price:           20 gwei
> value sent:          0 ETH
> total cost:          0.00373902 ETH

> Saving migration to chain.
> Saving artifacts

---

> Total cost:          0.00373902 ETH

## 2_deploy_contracts.js

### Replacing 'CryptoBoys'

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"CryptoBoys" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)

- Block limit:  672197500 (0x2810eb7c)
- Gas sent:     6721975 (0x6691b7)

When I wrote this function it caused the above mentioned error

```
    function getAllTokensMintedByUser(address user) public view returns(CryptoBoy[] memory result){
        
        uint256 k=0;
        result=new CryptoBoy[](totalMintedTokens[user]);
        if(totalMintedTokens[user]!=0){
            for(uint256 i=1; i<=cryptoBoyCounter; i++) {
            
            CryptoBoy memory cryptoboy=allCryptoBoys[i];
            if(cryptoboy.mintedBy==user){
              result[k]=cryptoboy;
              k++;
            }
          }
        }
        
        return result;
      }
```

Comment: There is a code size limit in solidity. It should be less than 24Kb. Use this tool to check contract size https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract-size

Answer (score 1):

Your contract potentially exceeds the code limit of 24KB.

However, you can try to manually set the gas limit used for deployment to your `development` network in your `truffle-config.js`:

```
development : {
 ...
 gas: 6000000
}
```